# Fork public repository into private and receive public commits

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Let's have public github repository (A) https://github.com/schacon/example

I want to fork this repository to bitbucket as private repo (B).

**I want to receive public commits from repository A to repository B.**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a new Private repository in BitBucket named `B`. Clone the `B` locally.
- Go to repository `B`. Add a new remote (say, repoA) with the URL of GitHub repository (repo A).

  ```
  $ git remote add repoA <A-repo-url>
  $ git remote -v                     # see the remotes
  ```
- Pull the commits/changes of A repository into repository B.

  ```
  $ git pull repoA master             # B's master = A's origin/master
  ```
- Push the changes to repository B (BitBucket).

  ```
  $ git push origin HEAD              # B's origin/master = A's origin/master
  ```

---

Fetch all the branches of repository A.

```
$ git fetch repoA
```

Create a new branch with the history of A's branch (say, `next`)

```
$ git checkout -b next repoA/next    # create a local 'next' branch = repoA/next
```

Push the local `next` branch changes to Repository B's `next` branch.

```
$ git push origin next
```

---

In future, keep Sync with repository A.

```
$ git fetch repoA
```

Now pull A's branch into B's branch or, just checkout to a new branch like above example. Then Push to B's repository.

**Note** `repoA` is your repository A's URL and `origin` is repository B's URL here.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! The original repository (A) from github contains two branches `master` and `next` and the `next` is the one I need the most. Now I did everything you mentioned but I don't see that branch in my repository.

Comment: and how should I receive new commits from repository (A) to repository (B) so it will remain synced? Thanks!

Comment: The `--all` in `git fetch repoA --all` doesn't fetch all branches.  `--all` is to fetch from all configured remote repos.  `--all` together with a repo argument will error.  Remotes are usually configured by default to fetch all branches, so simply `git fetch repoA` will get all branches.

Comment: Agree. Updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to do this:

1. Just strictly mirror a repo - not trying to do development work in the local copy
2. Do development work in your local workspace while pushing/pulling to 2 different remotes as part of your workflow.

For a mirror copy (e.g. all branches), its covered pretty clearly in github docs here: https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/. However, note that these methods are strictly for mirroring a repo, i.e. they create bare local repos that aren't suitable for doing local development work.

In a nutshell:

A. For a one-time mirror copy:

```
$ git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/A.git
$ cd A.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/B.git
$ cd ..
$ \rm -rf A.git
```

B. For an ongoing mirror copy:

Setup - first create target Bitbucket repo, then locally

```
$ git clone --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/A.git
$ cd A.git
$ git remote set-url --push origin https://bitbucket.com/exampleuser/B.git
```

Then as needed, pull changes from A and push them to B

```
$ cd A.git
$ git fetch -p origin
$ git push --mirror
```